# Delete SMS once received to inbox

Tags: android

First of all I would like to clarify that this question is not a duplicate of any other question as for the following reason:

I would like to delete the SMS **once it reaches the inbox** and **not before reaching the inbox**,
because if I want to delete the SMS before reaching the inbox I will have to use what's called `BroadcastReceiver` and set its `priority` to `1000` ( which is the *maximum* ). However, what if there is another application using the same priority? Android will choose one of them arbitrarily, in other words, it is not guaranteed that it's my application who's gonna take care of the SMS received as there might be another application on the mobile having the same priority. For such reason, I would like to listen to the inbox, and once it is received, i check its characteristics and delete it.

P.S: I have experience with handling SMS **before** reaching the inbox, my question now is handling the SMS **once it reaches** the inbox, this is what interests me.

Appreciating your support!

Comment: If two apps have a tie on their priority, Android will order them by install date. That is to say, whichever was installed first, will get the SMS first. Its not arbitrary.

Comment: ok it's the same thing, it means that if my app was not installed first, then it will not be able to take care of the received sms. Or will it be able to take care of it once the first app has finished dealing with it?

Comment: It depends. If the first app is something like GoSMS which will insert it into the inbox itself, then aborting the broadcast won't do much. If the first app is something that scans incoming texts for keywords and does s security lock based on it, then you'll still be able to delete it

Comment: ok this is why I do still need to listen to the inbox every interval of time in case it was not aborted by my app.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, but you have not asked a question other than the rhetorical "what if there is another application using the same priority?" You have not indicated what you tried and why it did not work. You also have not indicated how you intend to deal with all the possible SMS clients, and the fact that not all of them necessarily have an "inbox" that you can mess with.

Comment: The question was simply how to check the inbox every interval of time to check for incoming sms and delete it if it has certain specific characteristics